# How can i customize the js new Date() instance

Tags: javascript

When i use the new Date() instance i get something like

```
2020-12-10T12:30:18.108Z
```

the problem is that by me the hour on my local machine is 13:30 - but it gives me one hour earlier so 12:30 in the current time. How can i customize to give me the right time of my local machine ?

Also i don't know the meaning of the last four character after the . sign

```
108Z
```

all i need is to insert in my db the hour and the date without this signs

```
2020-12-10T12:30:18
```

is there any other solution except manupulating the string directly ?

Comment: Maybe check out a library like moment.js. If not for anything else the docs will give you an idea on just how complex dates can be

Comment: Z means Zulu time. Which is a term for the UTC / GMT timezone.

Comment: `108Z` -> 108 milliseconds, and `Z` is the time zone signifier for UTC (+00:00). If you're getting an hour earlier than your local time, then it means you're at a +01:00 time zone, like central Europe.

Comment: @Devilscomrade Well, not really. It's the part of the ISO datetime format, snd means the UTC...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using UTC Date I guess. You can try to use `.toLocaleString()` on your date time object.

**Maybe use like that**

```
var datetime = new Date();
var now = datetime.toLocaleString();
```

This should get you something like this: `10/12/2020, 8:47:15 AM`

#### UPDATED

Another option if you want to maintain format and just remove `T` and `Z` characters is to replace string

You can try this:

```
var datetime = new Date();
var now = datetime.toISOString().replace('Z', '').replace('T', '');
```

Comment: DON'T REMOVE THE `Z`! You're losing the timezone information and very likely introducing a bug in the program!

Comment: @VLAZ Yes i know that, but I'm added a `Another option if you want to maintain format` for choosing use or not